# How to solve this even symmetry question?

Tags: discrete-signals, dft, symmetry, exam

I have my DSP final soon and I have been reviewing some past exams. Here is a question from one of these exams:

> Let x[n] be a real valued finite duration signal in n $\in [0,N]$. Another signal $x_1[n]$ is defined as:
> $$x_1[n] =
>     \begin{cases}
>             x[n], &         \text{if } n=0 \; or \; n=N ,\\
>             c x[n], &         \text{if } n \in [1, \: N-1],\\
>             c x[2N-n]    &      \text{if } n \in [N+1,\: 2N-1]    
>     \end{cases}
> $$
> where $c$ is a real valued constant and $x_1[n]$ is a finite duration signal $\in [0, \: 2N-1]$ 
> a) Show that $\mathrm{X}_1(k) = DFT_{2N}\{x_1[n]\}$ is real valued$.$
>
> b) Write $\mathrm{X}_1(k) = DFT_{2N}\{x_1[n]\} = \sum_{n=0}^{N}x[n]\phi_k[n] \:, \; k = 0,...,2N-1$ where $\phi_k[n]$'s have real values. Find those $\phi_k [n]$'s$.$
>
> c) Show that $\mathrm{X}_1(k) = \mathrm{X}_1(-k)_{\text{mod}\:2N}$

Now I know that this question is testing the conjugate/even symmetric property of the DFT. I can handle c) but I am not sure how to approach parts a) and b). Here is my attempt for a) and solution for c):

**a)**
The DFT is defined as follows: $X[k] = \sum\limits_{n=0}^{N-1} x[n] e^{-j 2 \pi nk/N}$

In our case let $2N=M$ and plug in $x_1[n]$ into the DFT equation:

$$X_1[k] = \sum\limits_{n=0}^{M-1} x_1[n] e^{-j 2 \pi\frac nMk}$$
$$X_1[k] = x[0] +  c\cdot \sum\limits_{n=1}^{N-1} x[n] e^{-j 2 \pi\frac nMk} + (x[N]\cdot(-1)^k) + c\cdot\underbrace{\sum\limits_{n=N+1}^{2N-1} x[2N-n] e^{-j 2 \pi\frac nMk}}_{G}$$
Let's work on $G$:
$$G = \sum\limits_{n=N+1}^{2N-1} x[2N-n] e^{-j 2 \pi\frac nMk} \quad\quad \text{Replace $n$ with $n+N$}$$
\begin{align}
G &= \sum\limits_{n=1}^{N-1} x[N-n] e^{-j 2 \pi\frac {(n+N)}{M}k}\\
G &= (-1)^k\sum\limits_{n=1}^{N-1} x[N-n] e^{-j 2 \pi\frac nMk}\\
\end{align}

I don't know how to proceed from here. Perhaps it would be easier to prove that $x_1[n]$ is symmetric but I am not sure if that suffices.

Here is my solution for **c)** which I assume is wholly correct.

**c)**
Just keep in mind that since $x[n]$ is real $x_1[n]$ is also real and also assuming that $X_1(k)$ is real as asked to prove in **a)**.
\begin{align}
X_1(k) &= \sum_{n=0}^{M-1}x_1[n]e^{-j2\pi k\frac nM}\\
X_1^*(-k) &= \left(\sum_{n=0}^{M-1}x_1[n]e^{-j2\pi (-k)\frac nM}\right)^*\\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{M-1}\left(x_1[n]e^{-j2\pi (-k)\frac nM}\right)^*&\text{linearity}\\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{M-1}x_1[n]\left(e^{-j2\pi (-k)\frac nM}\right)^*&x_1[n]=x_1^*[n]\text{ since it's real}\\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{M-1}x_1[n]e^{-(-j2\pi (-k)\frac nM)}\\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{M-1}x_1[n]e^{-j2\pi k\frac nM}\\
&=X_1(k)_{\text{mod} \:2N}
\end{align}

And help for a) and b) is much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have shown for a) is actually what you should be doing for b). For a) you simply need to show that your given $x_1[n]$ is conjugate symmetric or even in this case.

Now for b) if we takeover from your $G$ then we can proceed as follows:

\begin{align*}
    G &= \sum\limits_{n=N+1}^{2N-1} x[2N-n] e^{-j 2 \pi\frac{n}{2N}k} \quad\quad \text{c.o.v.  $l=2N-n$}\\
    G &= \sum\limits_{l=1}^{N-1} x[l] e^{-j 2 \pi\frac {(2N-l)}{2N}k}\\
    G &= \sum\limits_{l=1}^{N-1} x[l] e^{j 2 \pi\frac{l}{2N}k} \underbrace{e^{-j2\pi k}}_{(1)^k}
\end{align*}

Now there is nothing stopping me from using $l=n$, it's a dummy variable anyways.

\begin{align*}
     G &= \sum\limits_{n=1}^{N-1} x[n] e^{j 2 \pi\frac{n}{2N}k}
\end{align*}

You already have a sum running from $n=1$ to $N-1$, so combine the two under one summation:

\begin{align*}
    X_1[k] = x[0] +  c\cdot \underbrace{\sum\limits_{n=1}^{N-1} x[n] e^{-j 2 \pi\frac nMk}}_{(i)} + (x[N]\cdot(-1)^k) + c\cdot\underbrace{\sum\limits_{n=1}^{N-1} x[n] e^{j 2 \pi\frac{n}{2N}k}}_{(ii)}
\end{align*}

Combine $(i)$ and $(ii)$ as such:

\begin{align*}
    (i) + (ii) &= c\sum\limits_{n=1}^{N-1} x[n] (e^{j 2 \pi\frac{n}{2N}k} + e^{-j 2c \pi\frac{n}{2N}k})\\
    (i) + (ii) &= 2\cdot \sum\limits_{n=1}^{N-1} x[n] \underbrace{\frac{(e^{j 2 \pi\frac{n}{2N}k} + e^{-j 2 \pi\frac{n}{2N}k})}{2}}_{\cos(\pi \frac nN k)}
\end{align*}

So now we have shown that your $\phi_k[n]$'s are indeed real and we have also found all of them as such:

$$\phi_k[n] =
    \begin{cases}
            1, &         \text{if } n=0\\
            2c \cdot \cos(\pi \frac nN k), &         \text{if } n \in [1, \: N-1]\\
            (-1)^k,  &        \text{if } n=N\\     
    \end{cases}
$$

for $k \in \{0,1,...,2N-1\}$.

And your c) is correct!